# Re-escribir archivo csv a txt, alineando columnas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, formato

## Reescribir archivo csv a txt, alineando columnas.

#### Este código contiene, al final, en azul:

A: El contenido del archivo.csv que me gustaría formatear. 

B: El resultado que obtengo del script actual.

C: El resultado que desearía obtener.

He intentado bastantes cosas, demasiadas vueltas para algo que parece sencillo y se complica debido a la entrada y salida en unicode.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from base64 import decodestring, encodestring
import re, json, csv

# Normalizo el contenido de archivo.csv
with open('archivo.csv', 'rb') as fn:
    fd = encodestring(fn.read())
    s0 = decodestring(fd)
    del fd

# Creo una lista de las lineas
rex = lambda x: re.compile(x, re.U | re.M | re.DOTALL)
line = rex(r'(.+?)(?:\r\n)')
lines = line.findall(s0)    # list of lines

# Extraigo las columnas de la lista de lineas
csv_reader = csv.reader(lines, dialect='excel')

for row in csv_reader:
    print row[0], '        ', row[1]


"""


################################# A: Contenido de archivo.csv
Joy,alegría
So + adj.,tan + happy
Reason,"razón, motivo"
,

################################# B: Obtengo este resultado:
Joy          alegría
So + adj.          tan + happy
Reason          razón, motivo


################################# C: Deseo este resultado:
Joy                 alegría
So + adj.           tan + happy
Reason              razón, motivo


"""
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, cambia la imágen por código en texto, te ayudamos con los formatos. Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y del mismo modo obtengas tu primera medalla, también te sugiero revisar cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas la buena redacción de preguntas, un abrazo :D

Comment: Ayudanos a ayudarte. Una imagen no es útil a quien te quiera responder, pues querrá probar tu código, sobre tus datos, y modificarlo para arreglarlo. No se puede "copiar y pegar" una imagen a un editor de código, y si tiene que teclearlo todo no se lo estás poniendo fácil.

Comment: Lo he intentado, no encuentro la manera de hacerlo bien (tampoco). Se me formatea en markdown. ¿Cómo se hace para mantener el formato de python?

Comment: @MGrosz Mira aqui: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo usando la funcion `format` y su opcion `Padding`:

**ejemplo:**

```
nombre="Stack"
apellido="Overflow"

#alinear centro:
print('< {:^20} >'.format(nombre))
print(f'< {apellido:^20} >')

#alinear izquierda
print('< {:<20} >'.format(nombre))
print(f'< {apellido:<20} >')

#alinear derecha
print('< {:>20} >'.format(nombre))
print(f'< {apellido:>20} >')

#opcion 1
print(f'< {nombre:<10} {apellido:>10} >')
#opcion 2
print('< {:<10} {:>10} >'.format(nombre,apellido))
```

**referencia:**
[python format](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: Y si en lugar de "Stack" pones: "Súper"

El problema está en el ASCII, es lo que me trae por la calle de la amargura. Pero gracias por el intento.